# map in R does not show the colors correctly

Tags: r, dataframe, colors, maps

I have a data frame which has FIPS and colors in it, but when I plot the colors, they are not plotted in the color they are supposed to be plotted.

Here's my data frame:

```
df = pd.Dataframe {'fips': ['01001', '01002', ...],
                   'colors': ['#ffffff, #fc9d9d, ...]
```

and I use map function to plot these values:

```
map("county", fill=TRUE, col=df$colors, projection = "polyconic")
```

I tried it, when all the values in colors column are equal instead of plotting that specific color, it plots black and when I have my real colors as depicted, it shown colors other than the actual ones.

Comment: your data frame is pandas in python. where does the map function comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using map (from the maps package), the colors must be assigned in exactly the order that the polygons are drawn, which unfortunately is not exactly the same as the fips numbers. So you need to construct the right color vector. For that, you can use match.map() and the county.fips dataset:

```
x <- match.map("county", county.fips$polyname)
xfips <- county.fips$fips[x]
```

now we have a vector of fips codes in exactly the right order. Note that some may even appear twice if a county consists of multiple polygons (e.g. islands). But we must still convert them to 5-character strings:

```
 myfips <- sprintf("%05i", xfips)
```

the corresponding color vector becomes:

```
mycol <- df$colors[match(myfips, df$fips)]
```

Now, at last, you can draw the map:

```
map("county", fill=T, col=mycol)
```